# Disable Option-Click download in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I frequently use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+click in Chrome to open a link in a new window. But sometimes my finger slips and I accidentally press the <kbd>Option</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Cmd</kbd>, which is the shortcut for downloading the link target.

Is there a hidden setting to disable this, or a Chrome extension that does it?

There's an advanced setting to pop up a save dialog for any download, but I expect this will affect intentional downloads as well. I would like to disable only the keyboard shortcut if possible.

Comment: Would also love to know this, happens quite often. There’s a trick with binding shortcuts to an extension but this does not work for Shift+Click unfortunately :/

Comment: @Biswapriyo I'm on a Mac. I've gotten used to going through the dialogue for all downloads.

Answer (score 1):

u can right-click a link then hit "open link in new window". This is what i use frequently but it is on chrome. tell me if this works please and if not, what search engine you use. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this works, but it's more work than Cmd-click since I have to select from a menu. I like to use keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it with chrome settings, but you can use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck) to map option+click to nothing or to open a link in a new window. Tell us if it works.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I put `option+click" as the shortcut and Do Nothing as the action, I reloaded my windows (and even restarted Chrome). Sometimes option-click does nothing, other times it shows the save dialogue.